# Custom event with custom trigger in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-mobile, custom-events

In JQueryMobile you can do this:

```
$(document).on("pagebeforehide","#pagetwo",function(){
  alert("pagebeforehide event fired - pagetwo is about to be hidden");
});
```

Is this possible with custom events? Something like so:

```
document.addEventListener("someevent", "sometrigger", function () {});
```

Comment: jQuery core supports custom events: http://learn.jquery.com/events/introduction-to-custom-events/  Are you having a specific issue?

Comment: I want to filter the event by trigger inside the function header, not inside the function. `$(document).on("event", "trigger", function(){});` instead of `$(document).on("event", function(trigger){ if(trigger !== "trigger") return; });`

Comment: @sollniss Not certain if interpret `$(document).on("event", "trigger", function(){});` correctly ? What is expected result ?

Comment: The function is only called when the event was triggered on "trigger". I guess I missed a "#" or "." there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```js
$(document).on("someevent", "div", function(e) {
      console.log(this.innerText)
});

var elem = $("div:contains('abc')");

if (elem.length) {
  elem.trigger("someevent")
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>abc</div>
<div>123</div>
```

See [.trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger)

Comment: This is what I wanted, but why does `$(document).on("pagecontainerchange", "#id", function(event, ui){});` not bahave like that then?

Comment: @sollniss Not certain ? Can post "stacksnippets" , http://jsfiddle.net , including `html` , expected result , to demonstrate ?